# Scroll UITableView to next table view then stop - SWIFT iOS8

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm trying to create an app that utilizes the fullscreen as the card for the UITableView but I want to swipe up and down to the next card but stop not keep scrolling. I'm using Swift instead of Objective-C.

Comment: Nothing yet but I've been seeing some ScrollToPosition call-outs

Comment: You better post something that you've tried, Because, the big guns here will fire and downvote you very soon.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds more like a paged UIScrollView or a UIPageViewController, either of which I would suggest is far better for it than a table view.

Comment: Thanks Matt! :) - Lets say I want to the PageViewController to take up the whole screen and when i swipe up/down it moves the new cell into view and stop (without unlimited scroll)

Comment: Sounds just like the example in my book (mine is across instead of up-down but that's easy to change): https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch06p311pageController/ch19p626pageController